# Vector3.Distance when the player is moving not working properly?

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine

I have a problem using Vector3.Distance method. What I'm trying to do is to make the enemy spawn in certain points in the map randomly, and when it sees the player it sets a boolean variable to "true" (which means the player has been seen) and it starts to spawn every 10 seconds (more or less) in the nearest point from the player.

Here is the code:

```
if (!seen) {
    TrisCoordinates tc = GetComponent<SpawnPoints>().GetRandomPosition();
    go = (GameObject) Instantiate (boss.gameObject, new Vector3(tc.GetX (), tc.GetY(), tc.GetZ ()), Quaternion.identity);
} else {
    Vector3 min = new Vector3(coords[0].GetX (), coords[0].GetY (), coords[0].GetZ ());
    float dist = Vector3.Distance (min, player.position);
    Vector3 temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < coords.Count; i++) {
        temp = new Vector3 (coords[i].GetX (), coords[i].GetY (), coords[i].GetZ ());
        if (dist > Vector3.Distance (temp, player.position)) {
            min = temp;
            dist = Vector3.Distance (temp, player.position);
        }
    }
    TrisCoordinates tc = new TrisCoordinates (min.x, min.y, min.z);
    Instantiate (boss.gameObject, min, transform.rotation);
}
```

TrisCoordinates --> class which keeps three coordinates (x,y,z) and which has getters & setters

SpawnPoints --> class which keeps all the possible positions where the enemy can be spawned

seen --> boolean variable which indicates if the enemy has seen the player

In practice, the problem is that at the beginning the enemy is correctly randomly spawned, when it sees the player it starts to be spawned in the nearest points BUT when the player goes into the forest (there are a lot of trees) the enemy begins to be spawned in further positions and it doesn't spawn anymore near the player. This happens only if the player goes into the forest, could it be caused by some kind of computation or stuff like that?

I also post the initialization of the list and the part which sets the boolean variable:

```
private List<TrisCoordinates> coords = new List<TrisCoordinates>();
...
coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (200.901f, 1.67f, 386.03f));
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (222.328f, 1.67f, 386.03f));
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (338.672f,1.67f, 338.672f));
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (424.3f, 1.67f, 369.37f));
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (326.24f, 1.67f, 236.99f));
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (305.3f,1.67f, 259.3f));
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (280.29f, 1.67f,160.22f));
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (226.96f, 1.67f, 298.74f));
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (264.97f, 1.67f, 292.15f));
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (271.54f, 1.67f, 320.14f));
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (245.01f, 1.67f, 328.54f));
```

Here is the full code for the enemy:

```
void FixedUpdate () {
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    transform.LookAt (player);
    Ray ray = new Ray (transform.position, transform.forward);
    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
        if (hit.transform.CompareTag ("Player")) {
            if (hit.distance < 20) {
                seen = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (timer < 0) {
        if (!seen) {
            TrisCoordinates tc = GetComponent<SpawnPoints>().GetRandomPosition();
            go = (GameObject) Instantiate (boss.gameObject, new Vector3(tc.GetX (), tc.GetY(), tc.GetZ ()), Quaternion.identity);
        } else {
            Vector3 min = new Vector3(coords[0].GetX (), coords[0].GetY (), coords[0].GetZ ());
            float dist = Vector3.Distance (min, player.position);
            //Debug.Log ("DISTANZA OLD = "+dist);
            Vector3 temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < coords.Count; i++) {
                temp = new Vector3 (coords[i].GetX (), coords[i].GetY (), coords[i].GetZ ());
                if (dist > Vector3.Distance (temp, player.position)) {
                    min = temp;
                    dist = Vector3.Distance (temp, player.position);
                    //Debug.Log ("DISTANZA NEW = "+Vector3.Distance (temp, player.position));
                }
            }
            Debug.Log ("DISTANZA PRESA = "+Vector3.Distance (min, player.position));
            TrisCoordinates tc = new TrisCoordinates (min.x, min.y, min.z);
            //Debug.Log ("X = "+tc.GetX()+"; Y = "+tc.GetY ()+"; Z = "+tc.GetZ ());
            Instantiate (boss.gameObject, min, transform.rotation);
        }
        Destroy (transform.gameObject);
    }
}
```

So, in theory, as soon as the enemy sees the player at a certain distance it sets the variable to true and for every instantiation of the enemy in the spawn points the variable is set to true and the enemy should be always spawned in the nearest points from the player. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't; I don't really get what the problem is!

Comment: How are you determining `seen`? Is it using a raycast? If so, the trees may be interfering with the raycast, causing your code to never enter the second part of your if/else block.

Comment: Which section of your code is spawning them in the wrong areas- the `if (!seen)` part or the `else` part?

Comment: I've posted the part of code for your answers; andeart the section of code which doesn't always work properly is "else".
Serlite the raycast works because its role is just to set the boolean variable to true when the player is at a certain distance

Comment: @Sharkstroke Uuuh...since you don't seem to be doing any physics layer masking with your raycast, I don't think your code precludes the possibility of interference by the forest's trees. Do you not have colliders on the trees or something? Since `Physics.Raycast` only returns the first collider hit, even if the player is within 20 units but behind a tree, the enemy won't "see" the player. As a result, the enemy will just spawn at a random position, and not necessarily the closest to the player.

Comment: Mmm I don't think that's the problem, because in every case the enemy sees the player when he is at a certain distance the variable "seen" is set to true and it keeps that value until the game ends, in fact there are no cases in which the variable is set to false again; anyway, I'll try to find a solution for this problem. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

No, the forest should not effect your distance computation.  The Vector3.Distance function will only take into account the two positions you feed to it, nothing else.
The code looks like it is looping through each element of your coords[] array, and comparing that to the distance, keeping the lowest value each time:  this looks correct to me  (though I would have made it an array of Vector3).

What your code does not show, and where I would suspect the problem lies, is how the coords[] array is setup. Nor can we see what class that array is.  I would suspect your problem lies with the initialization of this array.  But without seeing that code too, I cannot be sure.

Comment: I've written the part of code for the initialization.